# How to build a neural network with pybrain?

Tags: python, pybrain

I am new to pybrain and I am having a lot of problem in building a neural network. 
The documentation is not very clear to me and I did not find a lot of examples in the web.

I would like a neural network with one input, 1 hidden layer, 1 output.

```
x--->f1(x),f2(x),...,b---->g(z)
```

It should be a simple example. The hidden layer has different function and a bias unit. 
For this example we can consider `f1=f2=sigmoid` , `g` is a custom function.

This is what I have done so far but I am not sure at all that what I am doing is right.

And I have no idea of how to add the bias unit on the hidden layer.

```
class gLayer(NeuronLayer):

    def _forwardImplementation(self, inbuf, outbuf):
        outbuf[:]=g(inbuf)


    def _backwardImplementation(self, outerr, inerr, outbuf, inbuf):
      inerr[:]=derivative(g,inbuf)*outerr


print "build a network"

#Layer
inLayer=LinearLayer(1)
hLayer=SigmoidLayer(2)
outLayer=gLayer(1)
net=FeedForwardNetwork()
net.addInputModule(inLayer)
net.addModule(hLayer)
net.addOutputModule(outLayer)
#connection
in_to_hidden = FullConnection(inLayer, hLayer)
hidden_to_out = FullConnection(hLayer, outLayer)
net.addConnection(in_to_hidden)
net.addConnection(hidden_to_out)
net.sortModules()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a [BiasUnit](http://pybrain.org/docs/api/structure/modules.html?highlight=bias#pybrain.structure.modules.BiasUnit) as another hidden layer.

```
hBiasLayer=BiasUnit()

net.addModule(hBiasLayer)
```

Comment: are you sure that I have to connect hlayer to hbiaslayer?

Comment: sorry but I think I have to tell somehow to connect the biasunit with the outpulayer or not?

Comment: i you want the bias to shift the output function, yes

Comment: I want to shift the input of the output function. What can I do that?

Comment: bias_to_out = FullConnection(hBiasLayer, outLayer)